# virtual box not connecting to internet on mac after shared folder creation

Tags: networking, mac, virtualbox, centos

I have a virtual box(version 5.0.20) vm for centOS. By default Network adapter setting is

Attached to NAT

1. Name - Blank (nothing is written)

Advance Type

2. Adapter Type-Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (82540EM)
3. Promiscuous Mode - Deny
4. MAC Address-XXXXXXXXXXXX

Whenever I am creating a shared folder and mounting it . The internet connection stops working.

Tried changing to bridged connection. Still vm is not getting connected to internet.Please suggest some solution.

Thanks.

Comment: This issue got resolved after removing virtuabox 5.0.20 and installing virtual box 5.0.22 .

Comment: You may [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer), then accept your own answer. This way the question will be formally marked as answered which may help other users with similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

This issue got resolved after removing virtuabox 5.0.20 and installing virtualbox 5.0.22.